# Is it possible to create subqueries in SQFLite?

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart

My problem is the following, I want to make a query where I bring all (*) of a table (ELEMENT) and another table (IMAGE) may have 3 different images, but I only want to bring the first element, unfortunately with my query brings me 3 times the same ELEMENT but with different IMAGE since I have 3.

I want to bring 1 image from table A, B and C, but in the  table B or C i could have 4 or 5 images extra.

I tried with DISTINCT but it doesn't work.

I also don't understand why SQFLite doesn't support subqueries, if I want to do another SELECT, why doesn't it allow me to do it?

```dart
 final List<Map<String, Object?>> res = await database.rawQuery(
        '''
        SELECT DISTINCT
          e.*, 
            a.id AS aId, a.name AS aName,
            [...]
               b.id AS bId, b.name AS bName,
               [...]
                  c.id AS cId, c.name AS cName,
                  [...]
        FROM element_table e
          LEFT JOIN image_table a ON e.imageId = a.id
          LEFT JOIN element_picture_table ep ON ep.elementId = e.id /// nested table with ids between PICTURE TABLE and ELEMENT TABLE
          LEFT JOIN picture_table p ON ep.pictureId = p.id
          LEFT JOIN image_table b ON b.id= p.imageOne /// Here in the IMAGE TABLE B, i could have 2 or 5 images... 
          LEFT JOIN image_table c ON c.id= p.imageTwo 
        WHERE [...]
        ORDER BY [...]
      ''',
        [
          ...
        ],
      );
```

I try to do this because i don't want to use dart logic, this to avoid a lot of process extra, imagine that I have 2000 rows in the database? if I do some kind of map or for, my process takes time.

This can be mi Object :

```dart
class Element {
  final int id,
  final String name,
  final int imageId,
  final List<Picture> pictures,
}

class Picture {
  final int id,
  final String name,
  final int imageOne,
  final int imageTwo
}
```